# Excel Delete row if selected cell is in range

Tags: vba, excel

What it's for: 
I have a part list that changes per job.

What I am trying to accomplish:
If selected cell is not in column A then msgbox prompts user to "select part #"
Then only run delete macro if selected cell is in range A9:lastrow

Why only column A: 
If I can force them to select the cell in column A then I can use ActiveCell.Offset to add info to the msgbox asking them if they are sure that is what they want to delete and include other cells info about the part # they selected.

Above Row 8 is header so that has to be locked out.

Each of my part #'s has 3 rows that's why I run the "EntireRow.Delete" 3 times.

This is what I have now.

```
Sub DeleteRow()
    If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete this part?" & vbNewLine & " " & vbNewLine & ActiveCell.Value & vbNewLine & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value & vbNewLine & "QTY: " & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 12).Value, vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub
    If ActiveCell.Row > 8 Then
    Rows(ActiveCell.Row).EntireRow.Delete
    Rows(ActiveCell.Row).EntireRow.Delete
    Rows(ActiveCell.Row).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be more user friendly to ask the question **after** deciding that the `ActiveCell` row was `> 8` (and column was `=1`)?  Otherwise they are going to say "Yes" and then you are going to ignore them anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason for the active cell to be in column A in order to present the information you wish to in the `MsgBox` so, if that is the only reason you are trying to limit the location of the `ActiveCell`, you should be able to change your code to something like the following:

```
Sub DeleteRow()
    If ActiveCell.Row <= 8 Then
        MsgBox "This macro should only be invoked if you are in a non-header row"
    ElseIf MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete this part?" & vbNewLine & _
                  vbNewLine & _
                  ActiveCell.EntireRow.Cells(1, "A").Value & vbNewLine & _
                  ActiveCell.EntireRow.Cells(1, "B").Value & vbNewLine & _
                  "QTY: " & ActiveCell.EntireRow.Cells(1, "M").Value, _
                  vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete
        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete
        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Following @YowE3K comment, and maybe I am missing something in your post, but I think it should be something short like the code below.

Insead of `Exit Sub` if the user selects "**No**", just delete the Rows if he selects "**Yes**".

```
Sub DeleteRow()

    If ActiveCell.Row > 8 Then ' <-- first check if not above row 8 (headers)
       If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete this part?" & vbNewLine & " " & _
            vbNewLine & ActiveCell.value & vbNewLine & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).value _
            & vbNewLine & "QTY: " & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 12).value, vbYesNo) = vbYes Then

            ActiveCell.Resize(3, 1).EntireRow.Delete
        End If           
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing exactly what your issue is (which by the way you should state what the problem you are having is in your questions), I can only assume you are wanting the user to select a part in your code , and then do some kind of chekc after wards. Check this out:

```
Dim rNg As Range
Set rNg = Application.InputBox("Select something", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)
If target.address "something" then
end if
```

this should get you going.

For the people who are specially picky about answers without more info - i will delete if it turns out my answer is irrelevant

Comment: I'm glad you haven't deleted your answer. It helps readers see new ways to approach potential solutions to related (or unrelated) issues.